# Adding a Span Class in a Function

Tags: breadcrumb

Link: http://themeforward.com/demo2/2011/01/02/centered-and-captioned-image-longer-title/

I've tried this about 8 times and need some help.  For the bread crumbs (navigation trail on the top of the page) I would like to add a span class only to the  »'s that appear.  If somebody could add this in the function below I would really appreciate it!

My function:

```
//////////////////////////////////////// Breadcrumbs
function dimox_breadcrumbs() {
  $delimiter = '&raquo;';
  $home = 'Home'; // text for the 'Home' link
  $before = '<span class="current">'; // tag before the current crumb
  $after = '</span>'; // tag after the current crumb
  if ( !is_home() && !is_front_page() || is_paged() ) {
     echo '<div id="crumbs">'; 
    global $post;
    $homeLink = get_bloginfo('url');
    echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '">' . $home . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
    if ( is_category() ) {
      global $wp_query;
      $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
      $thisCat = $cat_obj->term_id;
      $thisCat = get_category($thisCat);
      $parentCat = get_category($thisCat->parent);
      if ($thisCat->parent != 0) echo(get_category_parents($parentCat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' '));
      echo $before . 'Archive by category "' . single_cat_title('', false) . '"' . $after;
    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo '<a href="' . get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')) . '">' . get_the_time('F') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;
    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
      echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;
    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
      echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;
    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
      if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
        $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
        echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
        echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
      } else {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
        echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
        echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
      }

    } elseif ( !is_single() && !is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' && !is_404() ) {
      $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
      echo $before . $post_type->labels->singular_name . $after;

    } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
      $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
      $cat = get_the_category($parent->ID); $cat = $cat[0];
      echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
      echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($parent) . '">' . $parent->post_title . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && !$post->post_parent ) {
      echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
      $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
      $breadcrumbs = array();
      while ($parent_id) {
        $page = get_page($parent_id);
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a>';
        $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
      }
      $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
      foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo $crumb . ' ' . $delimiter . ' ';
      echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
      echo $before . 'Search results for "' . get_search_query() . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
      echo $before . 'Posts tagged "' . single_tag_title('', false) . '"' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
       global $author;
      $userdata = get_userdata($author);
      echo $before . 'Articles posted by ' . $userdata->display_name . $after;

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {
      echo $before . 'Error 404' . $after;
    }

    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
      if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ' (';
      echo __('Page') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged');
      if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ')';
    }

    echo '</div>';

  }
} // end dimox_breadcrumbs()
```

Comment: You sure you pasted the right code, I see nothing about breadcrumbs or links there.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that!  Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
$delimiter = '&raquo;';
```

to:

```
$delimiter = '<span class="myclass">&raquo;</span>';
```

Comment: Mouse hovering over submit, Milo beats me to it ;)